# Why is the *ngIf statement not working in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I just created a new Angular 13 project and ran into the issue, that any *ngIf statement is not just ignored, but the whole div is not shown at all.
The html file I tested this with looks as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="true">This is text a</div>
<div>This is text b</div>
```

and this is the outcome (the console is also empty): [website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jVgd.png)

I have no idea if this is an issue with Angular 13 or something else, but I welcome any hints or ideas.

Comment: This code should work as expected. Is you compilation up to date, and your site is refreshed?

Comment: Yeah, it should be. As I said I simply created a completely new Angular 13 project (I double checked the versions) and yes, I did refresh the page (even with the JIT compiler running)

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to import the sub-module (in which the used component was included) into the app.module.ts file. After adding the import everything worked as expected.

I am just curious why the compiler didn't throw an error message of some sorts ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it's difficult to understand the problem.
Do you have some console errors?

One reason might be that you are not importing CommonModule in the yourName.module.ts file. In this case you will see an error like "can't bind to ngIf since it isn't a known property of 'div'"

Comment: Its a fresh Angular project with the posted html code added, that's why I didn't post more code (I can do so if it's needed). There is no compile error and the browser console is also empty. Thats the thing that confuses me, it looks like everything is working just fine, but then it ignores the ngIf divs ...

Comment: As I told you in the comment, check if the module contains CommonModule. If not, add it to the import section.

Comment: The CommonModule is already included in the imports

Comment: If there aren't error and you imported the correct module, then this should work. In the latest Angular release there aren't changes for this directive. 
You can try to reproduce the code and the bug in a sharable playground like Stackblitz or CodeSandbox